# How do I push loading view after UITableView selection?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiactivityindicatorview

Right now I am having trouble displaying the loading view. The process goes like this:

- Select row in UITableView
- Pop UITableView from mainview
- Push Loadingview into mainview
- Call long method that uses JSON Requests

The problem is that when I select the row in the table, it pauses there until everything is complete. How do I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to load the data on a separate thread. Personally, what I'd do is push the loading view into the main view then spawn a new thread that loads the data. Once the data has loaded, you can marshall back to the UI thread, dismiss the loading view and then present whatever view it is that you'll be displaying your data in.

Your implementation will look something like this:

```
// push loading view..
// spawn thread
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(loadData:) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

-(void)loadData:(id) obj {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    // load your data
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateUI:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:NO];
    [pool release];
}

-(void)updateUI:(id)data {
    // update the data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use GCD and send async request, when request finished go to main thread and do what you want.

```
//addProgressIndicator
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
    //call your request. Here could be your call back too, depends to architecture of your code
    NSDictionary *response = [WebService sendRequest];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        //removeProgressIndicator
        //do what you want after request is finished with your UI

    });
});
```